# How to move an animated AI character in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Current Situation**

I have a character and a "walking" animation.The animation is used in an animation controller. All assigned and done with the Inspector, no scripts involved. "Loop" is active.

When I hit the "play" button, the character's position moves according to the animation.

**Problem**

Once the animation reaches the end, the character gets relocated back to the origin point.

**Question**

How do I achieve that the character continues walking forward?

I read that I should activate "apply root motion" which I did, but that doesn't change anything, the character's position still gets moved back to the origin after the animation ends.

Comment: I think animation shouldn't really move character just to look like walking or running and rest should be handled by `Rigidbody`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do all your animations in place and move your object via code , change player position with code and let your in place run animation play.

Comment: The animations have "speed" by repositioning in them. One is running, the other is crouching, another idling. I really don't want to write a script for each of the animations when the positioning is already in the animation. Or do you know how to extract the position information from the animation?

Answer (score 0):

I really dont think that this can or should be done without any scripts.
Even currently playing animation should depend on parameters of the animator, as well as the movement itself.
And you won`t have to write a separate script for every state.
One script can get the user input, assign animator parameters (e.g. if the player had pressed LeftCtrl it sets 'Crouch' parameter to true and animator triggers related animator state/transition) and update character position depending on the speed and direction values. 
In order to save some time finding appropriate value of movement speed to match your animation, you can add an animation speed multiplier to every state in the animator and make it a parameter. In that case one variable with speed value will modify actual movement speed and animation framerate.